# How can I fight forest fires?

Tags: timber-and-stone

I recently had my first experience with a necromancer, but thanks to a small map I was able to get the troops out and make him permanently dead.  However he set quite a few things on fire before he left my map.  How can I keep the fire from spreading, and architect my encampment to be safe?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no way to prevent fire from spreading. It will spread to anything, but water and raw stone. This will hopefully be fixed in a later update with an ability to fight fires or resources that don't catch fire. From my experiences, fire will go out on its on eventually, but the burned area will not grow back.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make guard towers(assign an archer) on 4 side of the map. Make them kill the Necros before it burns everyhing...